# How to remove warning leaking from unit tests that requests with FormData body?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, msw

Currently I have these tests, built with Jest and MSW version 1.
Migrating to MSW version 2 creates a warning in the console with node18 and react app.

```
it('requests endpoint with a file as formdata', async () => {
  server.use(
    http.post('/endpoint', async ({ request }) => {
      requests.push(request);
      return HttpResponse.json({ data: 'some data' });
    }),
  );

  const file = new File(
    [fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '__fixtures__', 'file.png'))],
    'file.png',
  );

  const body = new FormData();
  body.append('file', file);

  // internal functionality
  await expect(postToBackend({
    endpoint: '/endpoint',
    body,
  })).resolves.toEqual({ data: 'some data' });

  body.delete('file');
  expect(requests).toHaveLength(1);
});
```

but also this

```
it('requests endpoint with a string as formdata', async () => {
  server.use(
    http.post('/endpoint', async ({ request }) => {
      requests.push(request);
      return HttpResponse.json({ data: 'some data' });
    }),
  );

  const body = new FormData();
  body.append('file', 'some form data');

  // internal functionality
  await expect(postToBackend({
    endpoint: '/endpoint',
    body,
  })).resolves.toEqual({ data: 'some data' });

  body.delete('file');
  expect(requests).toHaveLength(1);
});
```

This code:

```
await expect(postToBackend({ endpoint: '/endpoint', body}))
  .resolves
  .toEqual({ data: 'some data' });
```

gives this warning message:

> A worker process has failed to exit gracefully and has been force exited. This is likely caused by tests leaking due to improper teardown. Try running with `--detectOpenHandles` to find leaks. Active timers can also cause this, ensure that `.unref()` was called on them.

This **warning** message seems to appear only if `body` is of the `FormData()` type, with a file or a string as content, it doesn't matter.
No **warning** message if `body` is a string or an object.

Ideas on how to remove warnings from these unit tests?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same situation and opened an issue on the msw repository : https://github.com/mswjs/msw/issues/2078.

It seems to be a bug with msw 2.

Comment: Following your github thread

Answer (score -2):

If you're willing to drop the FormData function in NodeJS and use a bodyParser.
You can use the express app framework in NodeJS and a Content-Type www-x-urlencoded-form header on your xmlhttprequests to send the data to NodeJS.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

and on your client use:

```
    function z(url, data, async){
        xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xml.open("POST", url, !(!async));
        xml.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xml.send(data);
        return xml.responseText;
    }
    z("endpoint", "data=string");
```